# strstr function not returning NULL

Tags: c, string, ubuntu, strstr

I'm new here and this is my first question.

I have already searched for this issue, but not find anything of this kind.
So here it goes.

I'm writing a menu based program for a name database, using 2d array of characters. below is my main function.

```
int main(void)
{
    char name[MAX][25] = { 0 };
    char choice;

    while (1) {
        printf("******************menu****************\n");
        printf("i: input\n");
        printf("p: print\n");
        printf("f: find\n");
        printf("d: delete\n");
        printf("s: sort\n");
        printf("e: edit\n");
        printf("q: quit\n");
        printf("**************************************\n\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        getchar();

        switch (choice) {
            case 'i':
                input(name);
                break;
            case 'p':
                print(name);
                break;
            case 'f':
                find(name);
                break;
            case 'q':
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Input and print function is working fine, but I have problem in find function.
Here it is.

```
void find(char (*p)[25])
{
    int i;
    char str[25];

    if (count == 0) {
        printf("Empty database\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Enter name to search: ");
    fgets(str, 25, stdin);
    str[strlen(str) - 1] = 0; //Removing new line character at the end of string.

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (strstr(p[i], str) != NULL); //Breaking the loop, when first occurence is found among all the names.
        break;
    }

    if (i == count) {

        printf("Not found\n"); // if loop is not terminated by "break" statement,
        // that means strstr returned NULL for all names.
        return;
    }

    printf("Names matching with %s\n", str);

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        if (strstr(p[i], str) != NULL); // Again looping to print all the matching names.
        puts(p[i]);
    }
}
```

`count` is a global variable here, which is incremented in input function.
The `strstr` function always return true, even if I supply some gibberish name.
I am using ubuntu 16.04 gcc 5.3.1

I tried debugging with a breakpoint at `strstr`, it receives both the strings correctly, but always return the pointer to haystack.

```
__strstr_sse2 (haystack_start=0x7fffffffdcb0 "Imtiyaz", needle_start=0x7fffffffdc60 "abcd") at ../string/strstr.c:53
```

53  ../string/strstr.c: No such file or directory.

Haystack is `"Imtiyaz"` and needle is `"abcd"`

and here is what it returns.

```
find (p=0x7fffffffdcb0) at name_data.c:126
```

I dont understand what is going wrong here, is it from my side ?

and one more thing, previously I tried using `strcasestr()`, but compiler throws a warning "implicit declaration", though I included `<string.h>` properly.

please help me.

Edit: Ok friends, I will show the input and print function too to let you people analyze my program properly. Which are, by the way working fine.

```
void input(char (*p)[25])
{
    if (count == MAX) {
        printf("Memory full\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Enter name: ");

    fgets(p[count], 25, stdin);
    p[count][strlen(p[count]) - 1] = 0; //Removing the new line character at the end of string.
    count++;
}

void print(char (*p)[25])
{
    int i;

    if (count == 0) {
        printf("Empty database\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("********************************\n");

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%d   %s\n", i + 1, p[i]); //printing names with serial numbers.
    }

    printf("********************************\n");
}
```

I haven't implemented other functions yet(like delete, search etc.) as you can see int switch-case.

Comment: two of the `if` statements have a trailing `;` which should not be there.  the code should be checking for errors when calling `scanf()` and when calling `fgets()`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warning messages. then fix those warnings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a spurious `;` at the end of

```
if (strstr(p[i], str) != NULL);
```

Hence the `if` statement does nothing and the next statement `break;` is always executed.

There are 2 occurrences of this bug in the `find` function.

Comment:  such a silly mistake.  Anyway,  thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

`strcasestr()` is non-standard and only defined if you do this at the very top of the source file which uses it:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

As for why `strstr()` isn't doing what you expect, you will have to boil your program down a lot more to see what's wrong.  As it stands, there's a ton of code, including some (like the incrementing of `count`) which you have not shown at all.

Comment: Thnx for replying.  Edited to include other functions. plz have a look.